# how do I resolve the error 'app' has conflicting provisioning settings. "app" has automatically signed,

Tags: xcode, react-native, provisioning-profile, signing

I'm trying to build my app on a physical device.  Each time I try to build I get the following error.  I've tried clicking and unclicking 'Automatically manage signing, which results in Signing for 'app'requires a development team.  When I add my company's address/id I get the error message about conflicting provision settings.

Here is the error message I get
[image]

I should add that I inherited this project from another developer and that I was given the company's developer's id/password.

Here is the updated build settings page with provisioning profile set to automatic.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This worked perfectly for me.

Step 1:

Select the Project Target-- > Build Settings. Search PROVISIONING_PROFILE and delete.

Step 2:

Uncheck "Automatically manage signing", then check it again and reselect the Team. Xcode then fix whatever was causing the issue on its own.

Give a try :)

Comment: It helped me because in my case profile was specified through user defined variables so I didn't find it in build settings at first

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch to the Build Settings tab (as specified in the error).  In the Build Settings tab, you will find a setting where you can specify the Provisioning Profile for the build in the **Signing** section.  It appears you have specified a provisioning profile on your device, it is conflicting with the profile in the company account.  Change that setting to automatic (as it states in the error) and the error should go away.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I've changed the code provisioning to automatic as you instructed, but I do not see any change.  What's interesting to me is that when I attempt to pick a different setting.  It just gives me a blank space to type something into.  I've updated the original post with a second screen shot

Comment: After making those changes, I would save the project and restart Xcode.  Sometimes it gets confused when you make code signing changes.  Also, I would set your Code Signing Identity to iOS Distribution for "Release"

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks for the solution.